# Winston logger not saving logs correctly - two directories created

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

This is what my winston logger looks like:

```
var winston = require('winston')
var moment = require('moment')
var fs = require('fs')
var logDir = 'logs'

// Create the log directory if it does not exist
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir)
}

function formatter (options) {
  if (options.level === 'error') {
    return options.timestamp() + ' *** ' + options.level.toUpperCase() + ' *** ' + (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') +
      (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? ' ' + JSON.stringify(options.meta) : ' ')
  } else if (options.level === 'info') {
    return options.timestamp() + ' - ' + options.level.toUpperCase() + ' - ' + (undefined !== options.message ? options.message : '') + (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? ' ' + JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '')
  } 
}

var systemLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      }
    }),
    new (require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
      filename: 'logs/-system.log',
      datePattern: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
      prepend: true,
      json: false,
      timestamp: function () {
        return moment().format('D/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS')
      },
      formatter: formatter
    })
  ]
})

module.exports = systemLogger
```

To me it looks like everything is fine in the above code. However there are two errors... instead of creating one directory called '`logs`' inside the project directory, the program creates two directories called '`logs`' - once inside the project directory and one outside of it. Any idea why?

So in my actual program, I call the logger like this:

```
// winston logger
var systemLogger = require('./logging.js')

    systemLogger.info(Server Updated', {
       'ip': ip
    })
```

Nowhere do I specify that I want two '`logs`' directories, so Im slightly confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It is because when you are creating directory using "fs" module it creates new directory at same level in which your file exists. But using Winston it created directory (filename: 'logs/-system.log') at the project level.
That's why two directories are created.

Comment: Winston does not create a logs directory itself though? How can I fix this?

Comment: Im afraid this does not work, as winston does not create a folder called 'logs' itself

Comment: Winston does not creates directory, it will search the logs folder at the path where your server main file is running. If it finds "logs" folder at that path then it will create "-system.log" file in that directory or will not work. So first check the flow of winston and implement it.

Comment: Why did you delete you comment?